# Parsing JSON nested arrays

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to parse a JSON structure of nested data arrays.

**MY GOAL**

I need to parse arrays, save to the sheet iterating over categories.

> https://lsc.fn.sportradar.com/common/en/Europe:London/gismo/sport_matches/12/2021-07-03

**SAMPLE OUTPUT**

| d_date | name | home.name | away.name | status.name | result.home | result.away |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 03/07/21 | Rugby League | NRL Canterbury-Bankstown | Manly | Ended | 0 | 66 |
| 03/07/21 | Rugby League | NRL Canberra | Gold Coast | Ended | 6 | 44 |
| 03/07/21 | Rugby League | NRL Newcastle | North Queensland | Ended | 0 | 38 |

**MY SAMPLE CODE**

```
function jSON() {
  
  var destSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("jsonTest");
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://lsc.fn.sportradar.com/common/en/Europe:London/gismo/sport_matches/12/2021-07-03");
  var dataRes  = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  var dataSet = dataRes.doc[0].data.sport.realcategories;
  var output = []  
  for (var i = 0; i < dataSet.length; i++) {
    data = dataSet[i];
    var val = [];
    val = [
      data.tournaments[0].matches[i]._dt.date
      ,data.name
      ,data.tournaments[0].name
      ,data.tournaments[0].matches[i].teams.home.name
      ,data.tournaments[0].matches[i].teams.away.name
      ,data.tournaments[0].matches[i].status.name
      ,data.tournaments[0].matches[i].result.home
      ,data.tournaments[0].matches[i].result.away
    ];
    
    output.push(val);
    Logger.log(output);
  }
  
  destSheet.getRange(2,1,output.length,output[0].length).setValues(output);          
}
```

**CURRENT OUTPUT**

| d_date | name | home.name | away.name | status.name | result.home | result.away |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 03/07/21 | Rugby League | NRL Canterbury-Bankstown | Manly | Ended | 0 | 66 |
| 03/07/21 | Rugby Union | International Friendlies | New Zealand | Tonga | Ended | 102 |

**PROBLEM**

I can't iterate for each categories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need more loops; one for each nested array to get into it.

There are a few issues; watch your code indenting it makes it hard to read and easy to make mistakes.  Also you are using `i` which is the `realcategories` counter on matches (`matches[i]`) meaning you are only looking at match 0 of category 0 and match 1 of category one...

Try this: the other answer is more modern, but this is closer to where you're starting; so hopefully makes sense...?

```
for (var i = 0; i < dataSet.length; i++) {
    data = dataSet[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < data.tournaments.length; j++) {
        for (var k = 0; k < data.tournaments[j].matches.length; k++) {
            output.push([
                 data.tournaments[j].matches[k]._dt.date
                ,data.name
                ,data.tournaments[j].name
                ,data.tournaments[j].matches[k].teams.home.name
                ,data.tournaments[j].matches[k].teams.away.name
                ,data.tournaments[j].matches[k].status.name
                ,data.tournaments[j].matches[k].result.home
                ,data.tournaments[j].matches[k].result.away
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over categories, tournaments and matches.
Maybe something like this:

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://lsc.fn.sportradar.com/common/en/Europe:London/gismo/sport_matches/12/2021-07-03");
var dataRes  = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
var dataSet = dataRes.doc[0].data.sport.realcategories; 

dataSet.reduce((prev, category) => {
  return [
    ...prev,
    ...category.tournaments
      .map((tournament) => {
        return tournament.matches.map((match) => {
          return [
            match._dt.date,
            category.name,
            tournament.name,
            match.teams.home.name,
            match.teams.away.name,
            match.status.name,
            match.result.home,
            match.result.away,
          ];
        });
      })
      .flat(),
  ];
}, []);
```

Comment: Thank you, I chose the most recent answer because I was unable to export to the sheet. I'm sure your answer is valid too.